# How to use map::equal_range without a copy of the object?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a performance-sensitive function which uses a `map<string, ...>` to store some data.

I need to be able to look up values with any ***sub`string`*** of some other `string` as the key, **without** creating an intermediate `string` (i.e., the goal is to prevent a heap allocation from happening merely because I want to look something up).

The obvious solution is to hold two separate data structures (perhaps with another `map` on the side, to map from some key to to each string) -- one for the strings, and one for references to those strings.

But I'm wondering, is there a better way to do this with just a `map` alone, or do I *need* another data structure? I'd like to avoid creating too many extra indirections if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstood, but would your problem be solved if you could use a "substring view" of the query string to search the multi-map, instead of an ordinary `std::string` object?

In that case something along the lines below would work (using C++11-based coding):

Define a substring-view object type. It is constructed from a string and (from,to) offsets, but does not make a copy of the substring:

```
class substrview
{
  std::string::const_iterator _from;
  std::string::const_iterator _to;
public:
  substrview(
       const std::string &s,
       const std::size_t from,
       const std::size_t to)
    : _from(s.begin()+from), _to(s.begin()+to)
  { }

  std::string::const_iterator begin() const
  { return _from; }

  std::string::const_iterator end() const
  { return _to; }
};
```

In order to search the multi-map using the substring view, I suggest using the `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` methods from `<algorithm>`:

```
int main()
{
  std::multimap<std::string,int> map {
    { "hello" , 1 },
    { "world" , 2 },
    { "foo" , 3 },
    { "foobar" , 4 },
    { "foo" , 5 },
  };

  std::string query { "barfoo" };
  /* Search for all suffixes of "barfoo", one after the other: */
  for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < query.size() ; ++i) {
    substrview subquery { query,i,query.size() };
    auto found_from = std::lower_bound(begin(map),end(map),subquery,cmpL);
    auto found_to   = std::upper_bound(begin(map),end(map),subquery,cmpU);

    /* Now [found_from,found_to) is the match range in the multi-map.
       Printing the matches: */
    while (found_from != found_to) {
      std::cout << found_from->first << ", " << found_from->second << '\n';
      ++found_from;
    }

  }
}
```

For this to work, we only need to define the comparison operators `cmpL` and `cmpU` (one for `lower_bound`, the other for `upper_bound` – we need two because the comparison is assymetric: comparing a multi-map entry to a `substringview` in `cmpL`, and comparing a `substringview` to a multi-map entry in `cmpU`):

```
inline bool cmpL(
    const std::pair<std::string,int> &entry,
    const substrview                 &val)
{
  return std::lexicographical_compare
    (entry.first.begin(),entry.first.end(),val.begin(),val.end());
}

inline bool cmpU(
   const substrview                 &val,
   const std::pair<std::string,int> &entry)
{
  return std::lexicographical_compare
    (val.begin(),val.end(),entry.first.begin(),entry.first.end());
}
```

Working gist of the complete code: https://gist.github.com/4070189

Comment: But it will not find key "fo"

Comment: @DenisErmolin Yes, true, I implemented the search routine in this example only for suffixes, not for all substrings. It's trivial to do it for all substrings; however, the whole idea of searching for all substrings raises a number of questions not related to the "substring-view" problem. In particular, the question how to "continue" the search after finding matches for some substring "abc" when you then want to find matches for an extended string "abcd". The matches for the latter obviously form a sub-range of the matches for the former; ideally we should take advantage of that.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `string_ref` type which participates in the `<` relation with `std::string`.  In the TS [n3442](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3442.html), Jeffrey Yaskin proposes introducing a `string_ref` type influenced by Google's [`StringPiece`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/string_piece.h?view=markup) and llvm's [`StringRef`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html).  If you can use either of those then you're pretty much done; otherwise writing your own to the proposed interface should be fairly easy, especially as you only need a subset of the functionality.

Note that if you have an implicit constructor from `std::string`:

```
string_ref(const std::string &s): begin(s.begin()), end(s.end()) {}
```

then the `<` relation with `std::string` comes for free.